# How to send querystring data containing special characters using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am sending data (a string value) to my ASP.Net MVC controller the data is sent successfully. When I send special characters, like `.` and `&`, it shows an error like this:

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly)

Why does this happen? I can't find a solution for this. Please help me to resolve this problem.

```
$(function() {
    var link = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id= "_Description_"})';
    $('#btnSaveComments').click(function() {
        var description = $('#descr').val();           
        $('#btnSaveComments').attr('href', link.replace('_Description_', description));
    });
});
```

```html
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { id = "descr" })              
<button type="submit" text="submit" id="btnSaveComments" />
```

```csharp
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return view();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the string, which you can do by using `encodeURIComponent`:

```
$('#btnSaveComments').attr('href', link.replace('_Description_', encodeURIComponent(description)));
```

Note however that the `href` attribute is not valid on `button` elements. I believe you may instead want to set the `action` attribute of your `form`. Either way, the logic is the same.

Comment: Thank you for reply Rory McCrossan,This code also not working getting same error.

Comment: Given the information you've shown it should work fine. Check your routing to ensure that the path being generated is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when sending special characters in Url. You need to encode url string properly. Encapsulate in `encodeURIComponent`

`var description = encodeURIComponent($('#descr').val());`